# Unity - Custom Editor - data refresh

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I created a new window in the editor. It is intended for debugging and creating some mini test scenarios. For example, reducing or increasing the HP of enemies, subtracting resources, etc.
In the `OnGUI` method - I create a loop that iterates through the list of opponents and collects information about HP, ammunition etc. Via `GUILayout.Label` I display this information.
Unfortunately, this data does not refresh dynamically. And every few seconds or clicking on the window.
I don't know if I'm using this editor well. But I would like to have a section where this data will dynamically refresh for me - and will be part of the UI of the UnityEditor, not the Game itself.

[image: Editor window screenshoot]

Comment: Could you show the code for your editor window and how you do the refresh currently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.Update.html)

> Called multiple times per second on all visible windows.

like

```c#
private void Update()
{
    Repaint();
}
```

---

This can however get quite expensive and I think you could also rather use [`OnInspectorUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.OnInspectorUpdate.html)

> `OnInspectorUpdate` is called at 10 frames per second to give the inspector a chance to update.

like in the example:

```c#
void OnInspectorUpdate()
{
    // Call Repaint on OnInspectorUpdate as it repaints the windows
    // less times as if it was OnGUI/Update
    Repaint();
}
```

so it only runs at 10 frames/second but continuously so also if you don't e.g. move the mouse.

[`Repaint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.Repaint.html) basically forces a new `OnGUI` run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OnInsepctorUpdate()`, or if you want something that runs with the same speed as your game, you can call `Repaint()` in `Update()` method.

```
// This will update your GUI on every frame.
private void Update() => Repaint();
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I'ts nice shorthand.